# AngularJS form $valid set to true before validation completes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am displaying a validation symbol in the left nav of a page to indicate whether the form is valid or not. When I load the page initially the form's $valid attribute is set to true, then eventually it changes to false (as it should be given the retrieved input data). The result is my validation symbol flickering from valid to invalid.  Is there any way to prevent this? Currently the validation symbol is tied to a valid attribute on the $scope, which gets set within a watch. Is there any logic that could be added to the watch to check if the form hasn't finished initializing or validating? Thanks!

Here is my current watch code. The valid attribute goes from undefined to true to false after a couple different watch cycles.

```
$scope.$watch( 'sections.' + section.sectionName + '.sectionForm.$valid', function( valid ) {
    section.valid = valid;
}, true);
```

And the HTML to display the validation symbol:

```
<span ng-class="{ 'fa fa-check': section.valid,
    'fa fa-warning': !section.valid}">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the $watch function. The first time you will set "section.valid" as undefined. You don't need to watch manually. Each form directive creates an instance of [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController). So, you can check the form validity directly in view.

```
<span ng-class="{'fa fa-check': sectionFormName.$valid, 'fa fa-warning': sectionFormName.$invalid}"></span>
```

Comment: I have also tried without the watch by using sectionForm.$valid and $invalid as in your code above. It had the same result.